# Can't access state inside function in React Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following component in React:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../../services/api';

const Store = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  let pagination = null;

  const getProducts = async (page = 1) => {
    const { data } = await api.get('products', { params: { page } });

    setProducts([...products, ...data.products]);
    pagination = data.pagination;

    if (pagination.current < pagination.max) {
      document.addEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
    }
  };

  const loadMore = () => {
    const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;

    if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 300) {
      getProducts(pagination.current + 1);
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(products);
  }, [products]);

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map(product => (
        <p>{product.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Store;
```

My `console.log` inside the `useEffect` hook do print the products array correctly, and the component is also rendering the products titles correctly.

But when I try to access the `products` variable inside the `getProducts` function it doesn't get the updated products value, it gets the value I have set in the `useState` hook.

*For example, if I start the state with one product, calling `products` within the `getProducts` function will always bring this one product, and not the ones loaded from the API fetch, that were correctly logged in the console.*

So, when I try to add more products to the end of the array it actually just add the products to an empty array.

Any idea why this is happening? Being able to access the products state inside the `useState` hook but not inside the `getProducts` function?

Comment: The `products` state won't be altered until the next render after `setProducts` is run. Within your `getProducts` function you need to use `data.products` to access the new values. Perhaps create a temp variable like `const tempProducts = [...products, ...data.products];` and then use `tempProducts` to update the state `setProducts(tempProducts);` and also use `tempProducts` anywhere you need to access the updated value within `getProducts`.

Comment: I actually tried to create the temp variable like you said, but I just get the same result: `...products` will bring me nothing, so I end up only with the fetched products. The solution I found was to set the state in the `getProducts` function like `setProducts(previousProducts => ([...previousProducts, ...data.products]))`. It did work, but I still don't understand why the `products` variable is empty, even after the `console.log(products)` has showed me that the state was updated.

Comment: I am 100% sure I am calling the `products` after the state finishes updating, as all the products are already being showed in the browser when the `loadMore` calls the `getProducts` again.

Comment: I think I did not explain it well. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/10447393 from [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). If that's not the same problem you are experiencing, then I apologize for misunderstanding.

Comment: Yeah, the answer actually did help a lot, thank you so much for linking it! :)

Comment: You're very welcome! I only learned of this behavior earlier this week, so I'm happy to be able to pass the knowledge on to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the `getProducts` is using the value `products` had when `getProducts` was being declared, not the one `products` has when the  `getProducts` function is called. This is always the case when you want to access the most recent state directly in non-inline functions. Mostly, you will need to pass the updated value through the function arguments.

But this is not an option in your case. The only option in your case is to use the previous value as the argument from a callback passed to setState (in your case, `setProducts`).

Hope this helps someone else in future :).