# React Native updated state is using initial state when calling it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I just came across with the weird issue in my application. I have defined state in a functional component, I am able to update the state which i am clearly able to see through useEffect by passing it as dependency. But when i am calling the state inside `handleValidatePin` function it is showing the initial value.

```
const ChangePin=(props:Props)=>{
       const [pin, setPIN] = useState("");

        console.log("Calling", pin); //printing updated state
    
      function handleValidatePin() {
        console.log("PIN:", pin); // printing initial state [Empty String]
        setLoading(true);
        if (pin !== PIN) {
          pinInputRef.current?.shake();
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            setPINLocal(pin);
            setLoading(false);
            setToast({ type: "success", message: "PIN changed successfully!" });
            props.handleCloseSheet();
          }, 2000);
        }
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Updated PIN:", pin); //printing updated state
      }, [pin]);
    return(
<View/>
  .....
</View
)

}
```

Comment: how do you call `handleValidatePin`?

Comment: I'm not sure why `console.log("PIN:", pin)` gives your stale value, but `setTimeout(.... setPINLocal(pin) ...., 2000)` will definitely have issues with stale `pin` if your component updates `pin` after timer initialized but before it has been executed(in that window of 2s range).

Comment: Hi @skyboyer, I am calling handleValidatePIN through onPress event from a Button

Comment: @skyboyer Just to let you know setPINLocal is a redux action. I wanted to store the new PIN there

Comment: If `setPINLocal()` is REDUX, where is the call to `setPIN`? That should be the first effect of clicking the button.

Comment: setPIN is called in onTextChange event of the TextInput

Answer (score 0):

`function handleValidatePin()` is using closure to obtain the value of `pin`, but updates to state are running on the React fibre. The function will only be re-created (and therefore get a new closure value) if something else causes the component to re-render.

React has `useCallback()` to allow the function to explicitly see the new closure value, from the [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```js
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
)
```

So this should work (similar to useEffect, )

```js
const handleValidatePin = useCallback(() => {
  console.log("PIN:", pin)
  ...
}, [pin])
```

Obviously, if you can pass in the pin value from the click handler, you would not need to wrap in useCallback and recreate the function,

```js
function handleValidatePin(pin) {
  console.log("PIN:", pin)
  ...
}
```

In fact, you could then move the function outside the component for a small optimization (the function will never recreate on re-render).

---

**Tested with**

I ran up a basic React Native `expo init app`. The value of `pin` is always up to date inside `validate()` for this simple app.

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [pin, setPin] = useState()

  const validate = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('validate pin', pin)
  }, [pin])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect pin', pin)
  }, [pin])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <input onChange={(e) => setPin(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={(e) => validate()} >Validate</button>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried wrapping the function with useCallback but still getting the same output. I am able to get the updated state outside anywhere but not inside a function.

Comment: My Problem is exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458187/cant-access-state-inside-function-in-react-function-component but i am still not able to get the workaround

Comment: It should work if pin is in the dependency list, will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Tested it, can't reproduce - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using **your own button** (custom) or **built-in button** (import from react-native). So I suggest that:
The case you are using **your own button**: Make sure you **do not** using `React.memo` with `areEqual` function always return **true** or you use `JSON.stringify` to compare **prevProps** with **nextProps** (not expectedly when having function as **props**) in your **customized button**. Remove `React.memo` and see the result.

I hope it should work!